# Executing a Clojure script from Java. Unable to resolve classname, script dependencies

Tags: clojure

I need to write a Clojure script to execute from Java, as follows:

```
    try{
        RT.loadResourceScript("clojure/pdm-reader.clj");
        Var foo = RT.var("clojure.pdm-reader", "hello");
        result = foo.invoke("message");
        System.out.println(result.getClass().getName());

    }catch (IOException e){}
```

In Clojure script I am required to use HSSF POI. How is it possible to resolve this dependency? Doing

```
(:import [org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel HSSFWorkbook])
```

throws exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: HSSFWorkbook.
```

I have read that it is possible to create a .clojure file to insert script dependencies.
How can I do that?

Comment: Is HSSF POI in your class path?

Comment: Actually it is as simple as adding a .clojure file in the same location where the script resides and then adding that jar files separated by colons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is as simple as adding a .clojure file in the same location where the script resides and then adding that jar files separated by colons.